# Can I surface mount a retro wall mount sink in any way?

Tags: sink, vanity, custom-cabinetry

I just bought a vintage 1950's tub, toilet and sink. (the toilet and sink are "new" in the box.. never installed! ) This is the square wall mount type that has legs in the front for support. I Don't have the legs, and the bathroom I am putting it in is very small. The vanity is recessed into the wall. The left side is against the outer wall by the bathroom door, and the right side butts up against the closet. And this is the only space for a vanity/cabinet. I don't want to lose the storage or surface space that I have now. I was thinking it might could be mounted similar to a vessel sink some sort of way. I can have a custom vanity/cabinet built but would prefer to modify what is there or buy something premade that I can modify. I will of course be adding a new countertop but could really use some ideas/ suggestions as to how to pull this off and make it look good.  I can tile, sheetrock, put together and hung my own kitchen cabinets, etc. but this is a little different and need some guidance. The attached picture is not my sink but it's just like this.[image] Thanks!

Comment: Can probably build a cabinet underneath it, as long as the front of sink is supported.  Depending how bottom of sink is, might need small 45 degree corners in front corners.

Comment: Really you should show pictures of your actual sink so it's crystal clear how it was intended to mount and how the mounting holes are placed.  That said, if it originally had legs, it needs front support.  If you don't want to build legs for front support, triangular brackets to the wall will be fine if you design them right.  Sinks are mounted at sitting height and people also climb on them to clean things or change lightbulbs, so you better be sure it can support the weight of a person.

Comment: "People climb on" sinks to change lightbulbs? That's a good way to rip a sink off the wall, crack the porcelain, break your leg, or some other bad outcome. Has no one heard of step stools or ladders?